# Connection pool in Istio

Tags: connection-pooling, istio, traffic, circuit-breaker, istio-gateway

Currently working on Istio configuration. Below are the configuration

connectionPool:
tcp:
maxConnection:1
connectTimeout: 1000ms

http:
httpMaxPendingRequest:128
maxRequestPerConnection:256

With above configuration we are running jmeter script with 1000 user for 15 min. As report almost 34% of request either getting error out or getting drop off. But we are not able to trace those record. We are not able to see logs in application log in gcp. Thats correct as per my understanding gateway is not letting those request to reach to application.

But we are also not able to see those error out or dropped off request logs in Istio.

As I am very new to Istio, can anyone help me to understand where we can track those call?

Thanks

We tried today. Expecting to see some 502 or 503 or 504 http status code logs in Istion log.